# Error en Mysql Xampp

Tags: mysql, xampp

Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
If you need more help, copy and post this
entire log window on the forums.

En el administrador de tareas no hay ninguna aplicación llamada mysql.exe ejecutándose en segundo plano.
Es la segunda vez que me pasa.

Comment: ¿Por casualidad tienes otro servidor web u otro gestor de bases de datos en tu pc?

Comment: ¿Estas ejecutando Xampp como administrador?

Comment: En realidad también tengo instalado mysql workbench

Comment: Pues seguramente estará ocupando el puerto 3306. Deten todos los servicios de mysql workbench o cambia el puerto de este.

Answer (score 0):

creo que es que no se está ejecutando el servicio mysql.

## Primer paso.

- Ir a la ventana servicios, abrir inicio de Window y buscar la palabra "servicios" y accedemos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

### Segundo paso.

- Ya estamos en la ventana servicios, ahora buscamos un servicio llamado mysql. (amplia la imagen si no se ve bien)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
* Ahora que ya hemos encontrado el servicio, pinchamos y comprobamos si el tipo de inicio está en "Deshabilitado", lo cambias "Automático" o "Manual".

NOTA: Espero haberte ayudado.

Comment: Gracias compañero, pero no está mysqld.exe en servicios, también lo busqué en administrador de tareas y no aparece.
Tengo el MysqlWorkbench pero este se conecta con Xampp pero en cmd coloco netstat -an y el puerto 3306 no está siendo utilizado